# Which programming language is used to build Workday HRMS software?

Tags: programming-languages

Which programming languages and technologies are used to build [Workday](http://www.workday.com) software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workday uses a lot of technologies, but Java is the fundamental programming language used:

http://www.workday.com/company/careers/jobs.php